# Add symbology to raster - color ramp with manual breaks - in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, symbology, arcgis-pro, interpolation

I would like to add symbology to my raster. It is a single band raster. I have a color scheme already imported in my ArcGIS Pro Project. I would like to have a color ramp but with breaks manually fixed.

So in Symbology, I choose stretch symbology type. I select my color scheme.
Then I would like to manually fix some breaks. How can I do that ?

To be really clear, I want a color ramp. Therefore the Classify symbology with « manual interval » method, in which I can fix my class breaks, does not work.

What I would like is equivalent to the QGIS method : singleband pseudocolor with linear interpolation.Then I manually fix my breaks (or use a file text).

I join screenshots of my maps :

1)   in QGIS with the correct symbology 
[image: map in qgis]
[image: symbology in qgis]

2)  In ArcGIS with the classify method.
[image: map in arcgis]
[[image: symbology in arcgis[4]]

As you can see the legends are the same but in QGIS it is an interpolation, while in ArcGIS there are only the 7 colors.

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.2.0 and QGIS 3.

How can I do this?

**EDIT** 
It seems that I need this :
https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/color-schemes.htm
It says to use the "Color scheme" choice in Primary symbology. However I do not have this option...

**EDIT 2** 
I upgraded to ArcGIS Pro 2.5, but the "Color scheme" still does not appear. There are more options in the stretch symbology but none of them allows manual breaks.

Comment: You asked Pro for 7 discrete colors, and it provided that. If you want to request an enhancement to Pro for continuous graduations between discrete symbology values, then you should consult with ideas.esri.com

Comment: do you mean you think it does not exist yet ? I also try to ask Pro for color ramp but I can't fix manually the breaks. I'm surprised that it does not exist.

Comment: Pro 2.6 was released in February. 2.2 was released 22 months ago (with 10 intermeadite releases in between). The documentation is for the current release. Maybe you should try that before filing an enhancement request.

Comment: I updated to 2.5 but it didn't solve the problem, as I explain in my edit 2.

Comment: The documentation is for Pro 2.6. Either it was added then or it's not available where you are looking in 2.5.

Comment: I can't see where it is notify that is for 2.6. I can't see version, so I concluded it is for the last version of ArcGIS Pro. When I check for last version, on my ArcGIS Pro licence and on internet, I can only find 205 : https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/get-started/whats-new-in-arcgis-pro.htm

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a solution to do exactly what I wanted (a color ramp with manual breaks), so here is the fallback solution I used.

I decided to create a lot of classes so it almost seems to be a continuous color ramp.

At the begining, I had 6 colors breaks so I calculated to have 31 color breaks.
I selected Classify as Primary Symbology and I created manually my 31 classes. 
I saved this as Layer file to avoid doing this again.

Here is a screenshot of what it gives for the same area than in my question. Not bad I think. On some other areas in not as good but still nice enough.
[image: map with 31 classes in ArcGIS Pro 2.5]